# Unit testing WebApi controller that calls an async method with return type of void and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, void

I have a controller that calls a method that has a return type of void. I am also mocking up the object that method is a member of using Moq.  Is there a special way to setup a mock with a method that has a return type of void?  I am currently doing something like this:

```
_mockClient.Setup(m => m.MyMethod(It.IsAny<int>())).Verifiable();
```

The client interface is like this:

```
public interface IMyClient
{
    Task MyMethod(int i);
}
```

Here is the actual unit test:

```
public async Task DeleteNavMenuAsync_ReturnsOk()
{
    MyController = new MyController(_mockClient.Object);

    //TODO: This is always returning a 500, not sure why.
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = await MyController.DeleteNavMenuAsync(6);

    _mockClient.Verify(m => m.MyMethod(It.IsAny<int>()),Times.Once());
    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult as OkResult);
}
```

Here is the actual controller method under test:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteNavMenuAsync(int navMenuId)
{
    try
    {
        await Client.MyMethod(navMenuId); //Errors here
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return HandleException(e);
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  I'm only having this problem on methods that have a return type of void.  The method works no problem with live data, it is only an issue with Mocks and unit testing.  Ultimately I'm just looking to verify that the call returns an Ok HttpStatus.

Comment: There is not much point mocking out your controller. What exactly are you testing? Usually you will mock out the injected dependencies but run the controller for real.

Comment: The mocked method most likely needs to return a Task so as to allow the await to flow

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that actually reproduces the issue. If `Client.MyMethod()` throws a NullReferenceException, then either `Client` is null or some value that `MyMethod()` depends on. Neither is shown in your question.

Comment: There was not a NullReferenceException and that was not the underlying cause of the issue.  I would recommend removing the "marked as duplicate" as the link provided does not provide the answer to the question.

Comment: My comment doesn't change. Your question does not contain a [mcve].

Comment: I'm fine with your comment, it was complete enough that Nkosi was able to give the correct answer.  I'm just reiterating that this is not a duplicate question, whether you consider it meets Minimal, Complete, or Verifiable standards has no bearing on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyMethod` appears to be returning a `Task` given that it is being awaited in the example provided.

The mocked method most likely needs to return a `Task` so as to allow the `await` to flow to completion.

```
_mockClient.Setup(m => m.MyMethod(It.IsAny<int>()))
           .Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null))
           .Verifiable();
```